# Providing security for Restful Web Services into existing Spring security 3.1

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-security, restful-authentication

Hi all I am going to integrate authentication for my restful web services in my web application. I already integrate Spring security 3.1 for my entire application and its working good; but I am confused and I really stuck, how to integrate security for web services in existing application?
Here my existing security configuration for authentication and authorization.

**securityApplicationContext.xml**  :

```
<beans:bean id="myAccessDecisionManager"
        class="com.security.repository.MyAccessDecisionManager">
        <beans:property name="customAuthenticatiuonService" ref="customAuthenticatiuonServiceImpl"> </beans:property>
    </beans:bean>

    <http auto-config="true" once-per-request="true"
        access-decision-manager-ref="myAccessDecisionManager" access-denied-page="/jsp/errorPage.jsp">

        <intercept-url pattern="/*.web" access="ROLE_ANONYMOUS" />
<intercept-url pattern="productsService/*.web" access="ROLE_ADMIN" />

        <!-- Override default login and logout pages -->
        <form-login login-page="/login.works" login-processing-url="/j_spring_security_check"
            default-target-url="/login/validate.works"
            authentication-failure-url="/login.works?login_error=1" />
        <logout logout-url="/j_spring_security_logout"
            logout-success-url="/login.works" invalidate-session="true" />

        <session-management invalid-session-url="/login.works"
            session-fixation-protection="newSession">
            <concurrency-control max-sessions="100"
                error-if-maximum-exceeded="false" />
        </session-management>
    </http>

    <authentication-manager>
        <authentication-provider ref="customAuthenticationProvider"></authentication-provider>
    </authentication-manager>

    <beans:bean id="customAuthenticationProvider"
        class="com.security.repository.CustomAuthenticationProvider">
        <beans:property name="customAuthenticatiuonService" ref="customAuthenticatiuonServiceImpl"> </beans:property>
    </beans:bean>

    <beans:bean id="customAuthenticatiuonServiceImpl"
        class="com.service.impl.CustomAuthenticatiuonServiceImpl">
        <beans:property name="customAuthenticationDAO" ref="customAuthenticationDAOTarget"> </beans:property>
    </beans:bean>

    <beans:bean id="customAuthenticationDAOTarget" class="com.dao.impl.CustomAuthenticatiuonDAOImpl">
        <beans:property name="hibernateTemplate" ref="cessHibernateTemplate"/>
    </beans:bean>
```

now I am looking to secure my web services which as follows:

**My Web Service:**

```
@Component
@Path("/productsService")
//@RequestMapping("/productsService")
@Scope("request")
@Controller
public class ProductsController {

    @Autowired
    private ProductsService products;

    @GET
    @Path("/getProductsList.lbt")
//  @RequestMapping("/getProductsList.lbt")
    @Produces("text/plain")
    public String getProductsList() {
        return products.getProductsList();
    }
}


@Service("products")
public class ProductsService {

    @Secured("ROLE_ADMIN")
    public String getProductsList() {       
        return "Test String for Rest Web Service";
    }
}
```

**and last my Client class:**

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        Client c = Client.create();

    // plain text
    WebResource r = c
            .resource("http://localhost:8080/productsService/getProductsList.web");
    c.addFilter(new HTTPBasicAuthFilter("admin", "admin"));
    c.setFollowRedirects(false);
    System.out.println("Plain Text=>> " + r.get(String.class));

}
```

I am using customAuthenticationManager and myAccessDecisionManger for authentication and authorization of user.
When I use @Path annotation on controller and debug it then debugger could not go to my controller and throws an error for 402 not found and when I use @RequestMapping then it goes properly but when returning from controller I get the error at client side 302 found.
How to resolve this? Please help me.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You should use two http tags. One for your web application and the other one for your REST API. Let's say, you can use an entry point web/** for your web app and an entry point api/** for your REST API. You propaply want to secure your API with HTTP Basic, so your web app should work with form login (that uses java session) and your REST API with HTTP Basic authentication.
REST APIs are better secured with OAuth 2, but depending on size or audience of your application would be overkill.

Comment: Thanks for your reply; right now i am busy with another task once I free I will try your suggestion.